# Rails Sass compiles too slow in a fast development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

My computer runs at 3.6ghz with 12gb of RAM, and uses Windows 7 and RailsInstaller for developing Rails apps.

Back when i used pure css, there was no issue, but when i started using Sass and Compass, i have to wait over 10-15 seconds when i refresh to see new changes. (that only happens when i edit a .scss file)

Anyone knows what causes this on a fairly fast machine?

Comment: Have you tried setting the compass watch manually?

Comment: Maybe some kind of compatibility patch to work with Windows is the issue... Any other Windows users have the same issue?

Comment: @markus-tharkun I don't think I can use compass watch with rails, it says: `Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, 
you have left off the directory argument.`

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac. ruby 1.9.3p327, Rails 3.2.8, Sass 3.2.1, Compass 0.12.2, compass-rails (1.0.3), sass-rails (3.2.5) [gem list](http://pastebin.com/8nZLAZ0a)

Answer (score 3):

The sass compile times became significantly longer with the update from sass 3.1.x to 3.2.x.
There seems to be a specific concern as per Roman's response above, it's caused if you use `@extend` in deeply nested selectors since '@extend' does a lot of processing work. [Here is the link to a currently open issue on the sass project on github for this exact problem](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/495).

That being said, the reports on that issue is more like 90-100 sec compile times (104sec for my own personal project that uses `@extend` alot to pull in foundation/bootstrap classes).  So, if you're experiencing 9-10sec lags, yours might just be a general issue with the newest update being generally slower in compile times.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of too frequent use of the @extend directive.