# Imported Sass files not cached

Tags: sass

If I import a scss file which does some intense calculations which take a couple of seconds, is the output supposed to be cached?

style.scss:

```
@import "intense-calc";
body {
    background: red;
}
```

I guess it should, but it is not cached. If I change simple things outside `_intense-calc.scss` like `body { background: green }` the compilation process still takes a couple of seconds.

My question: If this indeed intended behaviour, what are my other options to make compiling faster, when making small changes, others than manually precomiling and importing the precompiled file?

`.sass-cache/` folder is being generated.

I am using Sass 3.2.8 with Compass and CodeKit.

Edit:
I just read this post: [Rails Sass compiles too slow in a fast development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546738/rails-sass-compiles-too-slow-in-a-fast-development-machine)

So since I am using many `@extend` directives in that file, that might be the root of the problem, but if it is cached, it should not be compiled again, should it?

Comment: https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass or stop the caching of sass files in you `compass_config.rb`.

Comment: But I do want it to be cached, not prevent it.

Comment: Is your `:cache` option to `true`?

Comment: I am using Compass, I cannot set a cache option, can I? Not listed here: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/

Comment: Its actually in Sass; take a look at this [link](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#caching). You can change the location and method of caching. This might be a good chance to fix your issue.

Comment: OK, so I've set ```sass_options = {:cache => true}``` in my compass config.rb with no compilation speed gain. So either caching is still not happening, or it's actually that slow despite caching.

Comment: i cant really tell with out more info. is there a sass_cache folder?

Comment: I updated my post, yes it is. I deleted it, and it was regenerated again.

Comment: so it is caching your files, which solves your initial question right? As far as speed, you probably right about @extend. You might try splitting the file up using sass partials so the entire thing doesn't have to be cached again. If you need further speed or that isnt an option look at the library in my initial comment. It moves sass compiling from Ruby to C which is many many times faster.  If this answers your question, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @agconti I am aware of libsass, but it is far behind the actual Sass lib, feature wise. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you're after, but perhaps you should evaluate:

1. Maybe you shouldn't be doing such intense calculations? Is optimisation an option?
2. Check that `~/.sass-cache` is actually being generated on compilation?

Comment: It's actually not that intense. It generates some grid classes by using mixins in loops. The root of the question is, should the output of those calcs be cached. I can't find information on whether it's supposed to be cached or not.